# How can I get windows print filter driver to compile in VS 2022

Tags: windows, winapi, wdk, windows-driver

I'm trying to create a filter driver.  I installed the Windows DDK and the new templates show up in Visual Studio Community 2022.  But when I create an XPS print filter driver, it doesn't compile.  Either I'm missing definitions or stuff is redefined.  ChatGPT is no help and giving up isn't an option.

I created an empty kernel mode driver project.  I added a DLLMain and a DriverEntry.  I include the following

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <Windows.h>
#include <ntddk.h>

#include "Logger.h"
```

Logger.h only has a bare class without even a defined constructor.  If I remove Windows.h, I'm missing defines.  ntddk.h is necessary for the driver project.  with them both, other stuff is redefined.  What is the proper includes?

I don't know if it's relevant, but here is my DriverEntry

```
#include "Framework.h"
#include "DriverBase.h"

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);

    DbgPrint("Print Filter Driver: DriverEntry called\n");

    // Register the driver's major function callbacks
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CREATE] = PrintFilterCreate;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CLOSE] = PrintFilterClose;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CLEANUP] = CleanupDispatch;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_WRITE] = PrintFilterWrite;

    DriverObject->DriverUnload = PrintFilterUnload;

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

NTSTATUS PrintFilterCreate(_In_ PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, _In_ PIRP Irp)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DeviceObject);

    DbgPrint("Print Filter Driver: IRP_MJ_CREATE called\n");

    // Perform any necessary processing for the IRP_MJ_CREATE operation

    // Complete the IRP
    Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;
    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

NTSTATUS PrintFilterClose(_In_ PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, _In_ PIRP Irp)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DeviceObject);

    DbgPrint("Print Filter Driver: IRP_MJ_CLOSE called\n");

    // Perform any necessary processing for the IRP_MJ_CLOSE operation

    // Complete the IRP
    Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;
    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

NTSTATUS CleanupDispatch(_In_ PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, _In_ PIRP Irp)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DeviceObject);

    DbgPrint("Print Filter Driver: IRP_MJ_CLEANUP called\n");

    // Perform any necessary cleanup operations

    // Complete the IRP
    Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;
    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

NTSTATUS PrintFilterWrite(_In_ PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, _In_ PIRP Irp)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DeviceObject);

    DbgPrint("Print Filter Driver: IRP_MJ_WRITE called\n");

    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION irpStack = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);

    // Process the write operation
    // Access the data buffer through Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer
    // and the length of the data through irpStack->Parameters.Write.Length

    // Complete the IRP
    Irp->IoStatus.Status = status;
    Irp->IoStatus.Information = irpStack->Parameters.Write.Length;
    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);

    return status;
}

VOID PrintFilterUnload(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{
    DbgPrint("Print Filter Driver: Unload called\n");



    DbgPrint("Print Filter Driver: Unload complete\n");
}
```

Comment: *"it doesn't compile"* - What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Of course when you include *windows.h* and *ntddk.h* at once and without different namespace you got huge count of errors. Include only *ntifs.h*  . Also you say *ddk* ? Such name already not used many years

Comment: I started by selecting the XPS Filter Driver template in VS 2022.  It started with ntddk.h.

Comment: @IInspectable  with #include <windows.h> commented out, I get errors like the following:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2061 syntax error: identifier 'PVECTORED_EXCEPTION_HANDLER' PB2020 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\errhandlingapi.h 136 

with both windows.h AND ntddk.h I get redefine errors:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2011 '_PROCESSOR_NUMBER': 'struct' type redefinition PB2020 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\shared\ntdef.h 778

Comment: I didn't post all of them because in either case, there are more than 100

Comment: @RbMm, it still fails with over 100 errors of :

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2011 '_GROUP_AFFINITY': 'struct' type redefinition PB2020 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\shared\ntdef.h 789 



#pragma once

#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <Windows.h>
//#include <ntddk.h>
//#include <wdf.h>
#include <ntifs.h>

#include "Logger.h"

Comment: @user9778277 - of course it fail. and you nothing understand.

Comment: @RbMm, dear God.  I literally tried your suggestion and it failed.  You really do NOT have to be so snarky about it.  I miss the earlier days of this site when this was a community for developers by developers to ask questions and gain understanding, not just be told I don't understand (that's why I'm here), or "it's complex" (so not helpful).  I wonder where I would be as a developer if when I was first learning C on Windows or Object Oriented Programming and I got stuck if someone would have just dismissed me instead of helping me.

Comment: OK, for the record, I solved this myself.  I have the DriverEntry stuff in DriverBase.c and a DLLMain in DLLMain.cpp.  By including windows.h for DllMain and ntddk.h in DriverBase.c, it compiles fine.

Comment: @user9778277 - no , you not try my suggestion . re-read **when you include windows.h and ntddk.h at once and without different namespace you got huge count of errors.** but you still include *windows.h* .. simply remove it. include **only** *ntifs.h*